# Java Datagram send and receive not staying in sync

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I have a device that replies to commands using UDP datagrams. I'm trying to come up with a way to guarantee the response is from a particular request. When I run the following code I get the first two, and sometimes third request, then it just hangs and times out the receive. I've tried a few different methods to resolve it (hence the synchronize and iQueuePointer receive timeout). Here is an example of a run:

```
Listening for X-Air responses
Sending X-Air requests
Servicing request 6
Send loop - bWait=true request.size=6 iQueuePointer=6
/info,ssssV0.04XR12-24-00-6EXR121.10 from 6
Removed 6
Servicing request 5
Send loop - bWait=true request.size=5 iQueuePointer=5
/ch/01/config/name,sPreach Mic from 5
Removed 5
```

Here's the code:

```
public static final Object socketLock = new Object();
public static DatagramSocket socket;
public static ArrayList<String> request = new ArrayList<>();
public static int iQueuePointer;
public static boolean bWait;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}

private Main() {

    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Thread(receiveRunnable).start();
    new Thread(sendRunnable).start();
    iQueuePointer++;
    request.add("/info");
    iQueuePointer++;
    request.add("/ch/01/config/name");
    iQueuePointer++;
    request.add("/ch/02/config/name");
    iQueuePointer++;
    request.add("/ch/03/config/name");
    iQueuePointer++;
    request.add("/ch/04/config/name");
    iQueuePointer++;
    request.add("/ch/05/config/name");
    iQueuePointer++;
}

private Runnable sendRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Sending requests");
        while(socket != null) {
            if(!bWait && request.size() > 0 && request.size() < iQueuePointer) {
                iQueuePointer--;
                bWait = true;
                System.out.println("Servicing request " + iQueuePointer);
                //synchronized (socketLock) {
                    try {
                        socket.send(new DatagramPacket(request.get(0).getBytes(),
                                request.get(0).getBytes().length,
                                InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.180"), 10024));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                //}
            }
        }
        System.out.println("sendRunnable ended");
    }
};

private Runnable receiveRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Listening for responses");
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
        while(socket != null) {
            //synchronized (socketLock) {
                try {
                    //socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    if (packet.getLength() > 0 && socket != null) {
                        System.out.println(new String(Arrays.copyOf(packet.getData(), packet.getLength()))
                                + " from " + iQueuePointer);
                        request.remove(0);
                        System.out.println("Removed " + iQueuePointer);
                        bWait = false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (!e.toString().contains("Receive timed out")) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Receive loop - bWait=" + bWait + " request.size=" + request.size()
                                + " iQueuePointer=" + iQueuePointer);
                    }
                }
            //}
        }
        System.out.println("receiveRunnable ended");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In UDP you can't assume that the responses arrive in the same order as the requests were sent, or indeed at all, and you also can't assume they only arrive once.

You will have to use sequence numbers in both, to match them up, or else not have any pending requests, and keep issuing a request until you get its response, and then you still have to deal with duplicates somehow.

NB You need to either recreate the `DatagramPacket` or at least reset its length every time around the read loop: otherwise it can keep shrinking to the size of the smallest datagram received so far.